# Calculate exit price in financial exchange based on desired profit

Tags: arithmetic

I have a bitcoin bot that is currently running and making some profit.
I will be revamping some of the software, but I would like to know how to set the appropriate exit price based on my initial investment and required profit.

Because I'll be using this over 10 bots, I'm looking for a formulaic way that will cross all the coins involved. An example:

I want to buy $4 of bitcoin which is at 100 USD. I want to make 50 cents profit.

I have searched all sorts of calculators on line, and spent over an hour on paper and pen to come up with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you buy something for $\$4$ and want $50$ cents profit, you need to sell it for $\$4.50$, so the price has to increase by $\frac {0.5}4=.125=12.5\%$.  If the starting price is $100$ the ending price needs to be $112.50$

Comment: So the whole portion I bought (0.04) has nothing to do with it?

Comment: Not at all as long as you express the desired profit as a ratio.  If you had bought a full one for $100$ you would be expecting $25$ times as much profit, which would be $12.5$ and again you would need the price to go to $112.50$

Comment: Ok. That does the trick. Thanks.